# What is the best way to manage a very large music library under Linux?

Tags: linux, music

I have a very large music library.  Digging though directories to find music is many shades of impossible.   I was using Songbrid which indexed my collection and allowed me to search it.  However songbird is nearly unusably slow for large collections and they have dropped Linux support.

Comment: Do you want a web based tool (to access anywhere) or just an application that runs on the desktop?

Comment: @Robert Leckie depends,  do you know of a cool  web app?

Comment: webapps.stackexchange.com would probably be the place to ask about a web app for that (if someone else hasn't already).

Comment: Why not just have it be like /Music/Artist/Album? That's how I do it and it works great. I've got over 400GB of music...

Answer (score 2):

If you're running only on a local machine, I recommend `Amarok` hands down. It has one of the best interfaces for handling large collections, and doesn't bog down under the size of my collection (20K+ songs)

If you're running over a network, `kPlaylist` is a great web interface to music collections, though I use `mt-daapd` to manage and make my large collection (20K+ songs) available over the network. The DAAP server automatically shows up in iTunes (my music player of choice, given such a large collection), and can be made to show up in Songbird or Winamp via plugins. DAAP will stream the music over the network so you don't have to manage sharing the files yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[gmusicbrowser](http://gmusicbrowser.org/) is the only application that could read my (600 GB) music collection without problems.

Comment: Please expand upon your answer—it's not very useful as it stands.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide at least a link and, if possible, provide some additional information about the software itself such as what features it has and why it would be useful to the person who asked the question.